# compiler for my web site

Tags: web-applications, compiler-construction, web, compilation

I am planning to build an algorithm web site that compiles the c and other language programs. I want to know is there any readymade tools/libraries for that?.

Comment: That strongly depends on how you plan to compile this C code. Client side? Server-side? How does the user retrieve the compiled result? Long story short, there are many ways to do it and will be different depending...

Comment: How secure does it need to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be mistaken, but assuming you have a unix server, you should have gcc or some form of c compiler already installed.  Then, it's as simple as getting your server side scripting language access to the folder with gcc, writing the code to a file, and compiling.

1. Write the code to a file.
2. Do something like `<?php shell_exec('gcc filename') ?>` with whatever compiler options you want
3. Execute the progam - `<?php echo shell_exec('compiled_filename') ?>`

Of course, you'll want to check that the file compiled properly, and doing it as I described without any security measures is a huge security hole.

Comment: I still can't get your point... can u please explain? My basic criteria is to compile a c/c++ code and print the output.... a function similar to codepad.org.. can i do that?